# Can't edit primitives of new added mesh

Tags: modeling

I encountered one problem that you can tell the menu of editing primitives are grayed out when adding new mesh, but when I enable the option of 'enter edit mode' for new object in preference, primitives seems work, but another problem came. It always generate another cube been overlapped as you can tell from the image below.

And once I uncheck the 'enter edit mode' option, new mesh added as object, the primitives menu seems working again, but now blender crashes if I change any each of parameters.

Please help! 
[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug in blender, you should probably report it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports for how.

Comment: But on the other computer, it works fine.    not sure what's wrong with this one.

Answer (score 0):

This just occurred to me and restoring factory default preferences seems to have fixed it.  Very strange behavior.